# Does Nginx has something similar to Apache mod_status?

Tags: nginx

I would like to know whether there is something like apache mod_status for nginx web server as well, basically i want to know all the requests that are currently processing by nginx process..

is this possible ?

Comment: The [HttpStubStatusModule](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpStubStatusModule) is similar.

Answer (score 2):

The FOSS version has the [`ngx_http_stub_status_module`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_stub_status_module.html), which you need to manually add at configure-time since it is not by default part of the binary.